# solidity smart contract api

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I have some guy who I believe is wasting my time. He is creating a solidity smart contract based on Ethereum for me and is already 3 weeks past due. He says the api call takes a very long time.

> "The api will be pushed to the GitHub. The APi really take time"

is what he says to me. I ask how long and he never answers.
Can someone give me an idea here - are we looking at hours, 3 days, 2 weeks, 2 months?

Comment: How would SO have any clue about how far your guy is in his work?

Comment: 'SO' ?? He's showed me the smart contract-  it is done. He originally told me 7 days to complete everything. It has been 28 days. I think I have been more than patient.

Comment: Sorry, "SO" = Stack Overflow. But still, what exactly do you expect by asking here? How would we have any idea?